# WCF-Custom oracleDBBinding: ORA-22062: invalid input string [40,7] at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal

Tags: oracle, wcf, biztalk

I have a BizTalk 2016 server and in my solution, I'm sending a "40,7" string to insert in a Oracle Database through WCF-Custom oracleDBBinding.

"40,7" is because the Host Instance user has the locale = es-ES.

In the registry is configured at Oracle level, NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252.

In all BizTalk 2009 servers, with the same configuration works perfect, but in this new BizTalk 2016 server always return the error:

```
ORA-22062: invalid input string [40,7] at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's an Oracle error so, any resolution would have to come through that channel.  It looks like BT/.Net/Windows is handling the numeric locale properly.

Comment: But how is possible that works with the old servers? Both call the same Oracle server and PL

Comment: From 2009 to 2016, I'd imagine the Oracle Client is different.

Comment: So have you tried using a Send Host Instance with American format?

Comment: What means "Send Host Instance" with "American format"? Sending the value in American format text ("40.7")?

Comment: I implement a WA, using value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); and now works. I don't understand how this application works in old BTS2009 environment.